# How to achieve this diagonal drop down effect with CSS?

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve a drop down effect in CSS like you see in this JPG.. Any ideas how to do this? Just need to figure out how to make it go diagonally ... Thanks!

[image]

Comment: given it's a web page, you could just use a dom inspector (e.g. the one built into chrome and/or firefox) and check out the css yourself.

Comment: Check out http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-create-diagonal-lines-with-css/ -- that should point you in the right direction!

Comment: To actually maintain DOM integrity (i.e. the element is actually diagonal), check out the skew CSS 3 transform and the Matrix MS filter

Answer (score 2):

Try this maybe helpful

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li ><p class="inner">Item 1</p>
        <ul>
            <li  class="inner">sub menu 1</li> 
            <li class="inner">sub menu 2</li>   
            <li class="inner">sub menu 3</li>   
            <li class="inner">sub menu 4</li>               
        </ul>     
    </li>
    <li class="inner"><p class="inner">Item 2</p>
        <ul>
            <li class="inner">sub menu 1</li> 
            <li class="inner">sub menu 2</li>   
             <li class="inner">sub menu 3</li>   
            <li class="inner">sub menu 4</li>               
        </ul>     
    </li>
</ul>
​
```

CSS:

```
.menu{
   margin:20px;
}
.menu > li {
    margin:0px 10px;            
    width:70px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    width: 120px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg,0);
       -moz-transform: skew(-20deg,0);
         -o-transform: skew(-20deg,0);     
            -ms-transform: skew(-20deg,0);   
              transform: skew(-20deg,0);  
}
.menu>li:hover{
   background: #4BA2E9;
   color:white;
}
.menu li:hover  ul {
   display:block;
 }

.menu li ul{
    display:none;
    color:Blue;
}
.inner{
        -webkit-transform: skew(20deg,0);
           -moz-transform: skew(20deg,0);
             -o-transform: skew(20deg,0); 
               -ms-transform: skew(20deg,0);   
                  transform: skew(20deg,0);  
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NYENb/9/)